# How can I refresh DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I'm trying to refresh datagridview after adding multiple records which were added programmatically, using bindingsource and datasource. My code:

```
Private Async Function RefreshData() As Task

    Await Task.Delay(15000)

    bs.EndEdit()
    daProducts.Update(dtProducts)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs 'Insert your DataSource here
    bs.ResetBindings(False)
    ...
```

When I call this function on form load event, it can't display any records.

Another thing is I get error if I don't use async function (because of setting DefaultCellStyle.Alignment).

My formload event: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/554747/

Comment: so your DataGridView is empty after calling RefreshData?

Comment: yes the DataGridView1 is empty after calling the function

Comment: but you're calling it in `Form_Load`... so if you don't call RefreshData dataGridView1 is not empty?

Comment: no it's not empty if I don't call the function. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful for you:

```
Private Sub updatedgv()
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.myConn)
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim str1 As String = "select * from tableName"
        da.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand(str1, conn)
        da.Fill(ds)
        conn.Close()
        ProductDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
End Sub
```

the explanation can be found in the link
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/372731/how-to-refresh-datagridview-in-vb-net

Comment: it seems it works. I need some time to try it. thank you for your answer.

Comment: @nikel if you have tested the code mark it as answer.

Comment: clicking a header doesn't sort after using your code. why is this happening?

Comment: I think if you add yourdatagrdview.Refresh() it will work as well.

Comment: you welcome, it is a long time i am away from VB, and if it worked plz mark it as answer.

Comment: it doesn't work :( they say refresh command only repaints the datagridview. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133946/datagridview-does-not-refresh-after-dataset-update-vb-net

Comment: sorry to hear that :( , have no idea why it is like that for you because i think the code that you use has nothing to do with this sorting issue.